# Appium iOS - Can I use two @name identifiers for different hierarchies in XPath?

Tags: ios, ruby, selenium, xpath, appium

I am using Appium v0.18 and I am trying to use `name` in two different hierarchies in iOS. But I get the error: `An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript`.

My question is: can we use multiple `accessibility identifier` in an XPath for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to answer on [github](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2966), this XPath is quite complex for Parser of Appium v0.18. So  it will not work.

Comment: You should modify your post to include the code snippets you provided in github -- the question makes much more sense with those details.